# Problema de programacion u logica para limpiar una lista en c#

Tags: c#, xml, serialización

No sé si está bien puesto el título pero si hay que cambiarlo lo hago. Y quizás es harto código el que pongo pero quiero que se entienda bien.

Planteo mi "problema".

Usando C# Genero un archivo xml, los datos de este los traigo de una base de datos. La estructura del documento es la siguiente:

```
documento
   cabecera
     elementos...
     elementos...
     n+
   documentosadjuntos
     .
     .
   bultos
     .
     .
   contenedores
     .
     .
   detalle
     item
        nro_item
        .
        .
        autorizaciones_organismos_externos
          autorizacion_organismos_externos
            .
            .
        descriptores
          descriptor
            .
            .
```

un documento que tiene de hijos una cabecera, documentosadjuntos, bultos, contenedores y un detalle. Este detalle puede tener muchos items, 3 para el caso, y asociado a cada item, ya sea el numero 1, 2 o 3 tiene autorizaciones y descriptores que pueden ser diferentes dependiendo del ítem.

Ahora, este es el código que me genera un item:

```cs
new XElement("detalle",
    from item in Items.GetItems(NumeroDocumento, CodigoDocumento)
    select new XElement("item",
        new XElement("nro_item", item.iNumeroItem),
        new XElement("codigo_arancelario", item.iCodigoArancelario),
        new XElement("cantidad_unidad_medida_arancelaria", item.iCantidadunidadMedidaArancelaria),
        new XElement("unidad_medida_codigo", item.iUnidadMedidaCodigo),
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.iUnidadesSet.ToString()) ? new XElement("unidades_set", item.iUnidadesSet) : new XElement("unidades_set", item.iUnidadesSet),
        new XElement("cantidad", item.iCantidad),
        new XElement("total_valor_cif", item.iTotalValorCif),
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.iTotalValorIngreso.ToString()) ? new XElement("total_valor_ingreso", nil) : new XElement("total_valor_ingreso", item.iTotalValorIngreso),
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.iPdmCodigo) ? new XElement("pdm_codigo", nil) : new XElement("pdm_codigo", item.iPdmCodigo),
        new XElement("autorizaciones_organismos_externos",
            from autorizacion in AutorizacionOrganismosExternos.GetAutorizacionOrganismosExternosItem()
            select new XElement("autorizacion_organismos_externos",
                new XElement("declara_certificado", autorizacion.iDeclaraCertificado),
                new XElement("organismo_externo_codigo", autorizacion.iOrganismoExternoCodigo),
                new XElement("tipo", autorizacion.iTipo),
                new XElement("numero", autorizacion.iNumero),
                new XElement("fecha", autorizacion.iFecha),
                string.IsNullOrEmpty(autorizacion.iGlosaAutorización) ? null : new XElement("glosa_autorizacion", autorizacion.iGlosaAutorización)
            )//fin autorizacion
        ),//fin autorizaciones_organismos_externos
        new XElement("descriptores",
            from descriptor in Descriptores.GetDescriptoresItem()
            select new XElement("descriptor",
                new XElement("descriptor_codigo", descriptor.iDescriptorCodigo),
                new XElement("descriptor_valor", descriptor.iDescriptorValor.Trim())
                )//fin descriptores
        )//fin descriptores
    )//fin del item
)//fin del detalle
```

Para obtener los elementos del *item* lo hago a través de un from que llama a una función dentro de una clase y le paso dos parámetros. En mi clase *item* tengo dos funciones una que se encarga de obtener la info de la base de datos y otra que se encarga de llenar mis listas y que es la que llama el from.

```
public static void ObtenerItems(int Ndoc, int Cdoc)
{
    AbrirConexion();
    SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand();
    comando.Connection = conexion;
    comando.CommandText = "Sp_c_XML_DocIngreso 'I'," + Ndoc + "," + Cdoc;

    var reader = comando.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        //elementos que rescato de mi base de datos y los guardo en listas
        NumeroItem.Add(Int32.Parse(reader[0].ToString()));
        CodigoArancelario.Add(reader[1].ToString());
        CantidadUnidadMedidaArancelaria.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(reader[2]));
        UnidadMedidaCodigo.Add(reader[3].ToString());
        UnidadesSet.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(reader[4]));
        Cantidad.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(reader[5]));
        TotalValorCif.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(reader[6]));
        TotalValorIngreso.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(reader[7]));
        AutorizacionesOrganismosExternos.Add(reader[8].ToString());
        PdmCodigo.Add(reader[9].ToString());
        pDescriptores.Add(reader[10].ToString());

        Nitem = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]);

//        AutorizacionOrganismosExternos.GetAutorizacionOrganismosExternos(Ndoc, Cdoc, Nitem);
        Descriptores.GetDescriptores(Ndoc, Cdoc, Nitem);
//


        x++;
    }
    reader.Close();
    CerrarConexion(); // cierro la conexion
    return;
}



public static List<Items> GetItems(int Ndoc, int Cdoc)
{
    ObtenerItems(Ndoc, Cdoc);

    //creo la lista de los items que llamo en mi Form1.cs
    List<Items> ListItems = new List<Items>();
    int i = 0;
    while(i <= x-1)
    {

        ListItems.Add(new Items() {iNumeroItem = NumeroItem[i],
                                    iCodigoArancelario = CodigoArancelario[i].Trim(),
                                    iCantidadunidadMedidaArancelaria = CantidadUnidadMedidaArancelaria[i],
                                    iUnidadMedidaCodigo = UnidadMedidaCodigo[i],
                                    iUnidadesSet = UnidadesSet[i],
                                    iCantidad = Cantidad[i],
                                    iTotalValorCif = TotalValorCif[i],
                                    iTotalValorIngreso = TotalValorIngreso[i],
                                    iAutorizacionesOrganismosExternos = AutorizacionesOrganismosExternos[i],
                                    iPdmCodigo = PdmCodigo[i],
                                    iDescriptores = pDescriptores[i]
        });
        i++;
    }
    return ListItems;
}
```

En mi función **ObtenerItems**, dentro del while guardo mis variables pero además, como acá capturo el dato del ítem que necesito, se lo envío a las funciones **AutorizacionOrganismosExternos** y **Descriptores**. Esto lo hago porque de esta forma le estoy diciendo *Para el ítem 1 traeme estos datos*, cuando pase al ítem 2 deberá traer otros datos y así.

Mi problema creo que lo tengo en esta parte, pongo el código de los **descriptores**:

```
public static void ObtenerDescriptores(int Ndoc, int Cdoc, int Nitem)
{
    AbrirConexion();
    SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand();
    comando.Connection = conexion;
    comando.CommandText = "Sp_c_XML_DocIngreso 'D'," + Ndoc + "," + Cdoc+ ", " + Nitem;

    comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
    var reader = comando.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        DescriptorCodigo.Add(reader[0].ToString());
        DescriptorValor.Add(reader[1].ToString());
        x++;
    }
    reader.Close();
    CerrarConexion();
    return;
}

public static void GetDescriptores(int Ndoc, int Cdoc, int Nitem)
{
    //se reciben la variable del nº documento y Código Doc y se reenvía a una función 
    ObtenerDescriptores(Ndoc, Cdoc, Nitem);
}


public static List<Descriptores> GetDescriptoresItem()
{
    List<Descriptores> ListaDescriptores = new List<Descriptores>();

    int i = 0;
    while (i <= x - 1)
    {
        //creo un nuevo elemento y signo llos elementos de las listas a cada variable para el xml del documento adjunto
        ListaDescriptores.Add(new Descriptores()
        {
            iDescriptorCodigo = DescriptorCodigo[i],
            iDescriptorValor = DescriptorValor[i]
        });
        i++;
    }
    return ListaDescriptores;
}
```

La estructura es la misma que la del ítem, pero acá cuando le paso el dato del item al **GetDescriptores**, llama a la otra función y me muestra los descriptores asociados al ítem 1, pero si después le digo "ahora pasame los descriptores que tiene que ver con el ítem 2" todavía tengo metidos los descriptores del ítem 1.

Entonces, se genera el XML, voy a ver los descriptores de mi ítem 1 y veo que tiene los que le corresponden y además tiene los del 2 y 3.

Si voy a los descriptores del ítem 2, también tiene todos.

Entonces, volviendo al problema. Sé que, de alguna forma, tengo que hacer que esta lista, después de que le paso los datos del 1er ítem y "los cargue en mi archivo" la limpie, cargo los del ítem 2 y se limpie. Pero no sé bien dónde tengo que hacerlo o quizás la forma en la que lo estoy trabajando es la incorrecta.

Si alguien sabe sobre este tema, le agradezco la ayuda, yo por mientas voy a seguir pensando.

Gracias

Comment: Donde defines x????

Comment: la tengo definida como una variable global y en este caso la uso para saber el numero de descriptores que tengo

Comment: Muy buenas @SebastiánMiranda, te recomiendo que mires como funciona la [Serialización XML](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/serialization/xml-and-soap-serialization). Creo que te va a aclarar como debes proceder de una forma mas sencilla, ya que crear "a mano" el XML me parece que te va a costar mas trabajo . Échale un vistazo a la documentación y comenta si tienes alguna duda.

Comment: y yo que había pensado que esta era una forma sencilla de armar el xml, gracias, voy a leer y hacer ejemplos y comento

Comment: @ElGerar para la estructura que puse en mi pregunta me sirve serialización? te lo pregunto porque estoy viendo tutoriales y todos tienen una forma diferente de hacerlo y no sñe bien como aplicarlo para mi caso, gracias

Comment: Como puedes ver para serializar debes convertir tus xml en clases una manera rapida es copiando tu xml y pegarlo en [convertidorXmlToC#](https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/) alli solo falta definir bien el tipo que tienes para cada propiedad, lo demas es abrir el documento y serializar.

Comment: Como dice @MiguelZarate las clases hay varias formas de conseguirlas, el mismo Visual Studio te permite hacerlo.

Comment: Como viene la estructura en tu consulta porque el SP se llama Sp_c_XML_DocIngreso  parece que ya traes una estructura xml, agrega solo una seccion de tu consulta. en tu pregunta.

Comment: El procedimiento, ese fue un nombre que le pusimos en la pega para poder diferenciarlo del resto. voy a ver lo que dice Miguel Zarate junto con la respuesta de @ElGerar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Muy buenas, voy a ponerte un ejemplo de como usar la Serialización XML tomando como ejemplo el fichero xml que quieres crear. No están todos los elementos que comentabas por abreviar, pero creo que si los suficientes para que se vea claro.

Por una parte el fichero xml tendría esta pinta (o eso supongo yo):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Modules>
  <Elementos>Elemento1</Elementos>
  <Elementos>Elemento2</Elementos>
  <Elementos>Elemento3</Elementos>
  <DocumentosAdjuntos>DocumentosAdjuntos1</DocumentosAdjuntos>
  <DocumentosAdjuntos>DocumentosAdjuntos2</DocumentosAdjuntos>
  <DocumentosAdjuntos>DocumentosAdjuntos3</DocumentosAdjuntos>
  <Bultos>Bultos1</Bultos>
  <Bultos>Bultos2</Bultos>
  <Bultos>Bultos3</Bultos>
  <Contenedores>Contenedores1</Contenedores>
  <Contenedores>Contenedores2</Contenedores>
  <Contenedores>Contenedores3</Contenedores>
  <Detalle>
    <Item>
      <nro_item>item1</nro_item>
      <codigo_arancelario>codigoArancelario1</codigo_arancelario>
      <autorizaciones_organismos_externos>
        <declara_certificado>declara_certificado1</declara_certificado>
        <organismo_externo_codigo>organismo_externo_codigo1</organismo_externo_codigo>
      </autorizaciones_organismos_externos>
      <descriptores>
        <descriptor_codigo>descriptor_codigo1</descriptor_codigo>
        <descriptor_valor>descriptor_valor1</descriptor_valor>
      </descriptores>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <nro_item>item2</nro_item>
      <codigo_arancelario>codigoArancelario2</codigo_arancelario>
      <autorizaciones_organismos_externos>
        <declara_certificado>declara_certificado1</declara_certificado>
        <organismo_externo_codigo>organismo_externo_codigo1</organismo_externo_codigo>
      </autorizaciones_organismos_externos>
      <descriptores>
        <descriptor_codigo>descriptor_codigo2</descriptor_codigo>
        <descriptor_valor>descriptor_valor2</descriptor_valor>
      </descriptores>
    </Item>
  </Detalle>
</Modules>
```

Para poder obtener dicho fichero me he creado las siguientes clases que me permitirán Serializar y Deserializar:

```
[XmlRoot("Modules",Namespace = "")]
    public class DocumentoXML
    {
        [XmlElement("Elementos")]
        public List<string> Elementos { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("DocumentosAdjuntos")]
        public List<string> DocumentosAdjuntos { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Bultos")]
        public List<string> Bultos { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Contenedores")]
        public List<string> Contenedores { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Detalle")]
        public List<DetalleXML> Detalle { get; set; }
    }

    public class DetalleXML
    {
        [XmlElement("Item")]
        public List<ItemXML> Items { get; set; }

    }

    public class ItemXML
    {
        [XmlElement("nro_item")]
        public string nro_item { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("codigo_arancelario")]
        public string codigo_arancelario { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("autorizaciones_organismos_externos")]
        public List<AutorizacionXML> autorizaciones_organismos_externos { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("descriptores")]
        public List<DescriptoresXML> descriptores { get; set; }
    }

    public class AutorizacionXML
    {
        [XmlElement("declara_certificado")]
        public string declara_certificado { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("organismo_externo_codigo")]
        public string organismo_externo_codigo { get; set; }
    }

    public class DescriptoresXML
    {
        [XmlElement("descriptor_codigo")]
        public string descriptor_codigo { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("descriptor_valor")]
        public string descriptor_valor { get; set; }
    }
```

Aquí añado el código donde me he creado un objeto de tipo 'DocumentoXML' y en mi caso lo he rellenado a mano, pero en el tuyo lo rellenaras obteniendo los datos de una `BD` o de un `Form`, etc:

```
    var docu = new DocumentoXML();
    docu.Elementos = new List<string> {"Elemento1", "Elemento2", "Elemento3"};
    docu.DocumentosAdjuntos = new List<string>
        {"DocumentosAdjuntos1", "DocumentosAdjuntos2", "DocumentosAdjuntos3"};
    docu.Bultos = new List<string> {"Bultos1", "Bultos2", "Bultos3"};
    docu.Contenedores = new List<string> {"Contenedores1", "Contenedores2", "Contenedores3"};
    //Detalles
    var detalles = new List<DetalleXML>();
    var detalle1 = new DetalleXML();
    var items = new List<ItemXML>();

    //Item1
    var item1 = new ItemXML();
    item1.nro_item = "item1";
    item1.codigo_arancelario = "codigoArancelario1";

    var autorizaciones = new List<AutorizacionXML>();
    var auto1 = new AutorizacionXML();
    auto1.declara_certificado = "declara_certificado1";
    auto1.organismo_externo_codigo = "organismo_externo_codigo1";
    autorizaciones.Add(auto1);
    item1.autorizaciones_organismos_externos = autorizaciones;
    var descriptores = new List<DescriptoresXML>();
    var descriptor1 = new DescriptoresXML();
    descriptor1.descriptor_codigo = "descriptor_codigo1";
    descriptor1.descriptor_valor = "descriptor_valor1";
    descriptores.Add(descriptor1);
    item1.descriptores = descriptores;

    //Item2
    var item2 = new ItemXML();
    item2.nro_item = "item2";
    item2.codigo_arancelario = "codigoArancelario2";
    var autorizaciones2 = new List<AutorizacionXML>();
    var auto2 = new AutorizacionXML();
    auto2.declara_certificado = "declara_certificado2";
    auto2.organismo_externo_codigo = "organismo_externo_codigo2";
    autorizaciones2.Add(auto2);
    item2.autorizaciones_organismos_externos = autorizaciones;
    var descriptores2 = new List<DescriptoresXML>();
    var descriptor2 = new DescriptoresXML();
    descriptor2.descriptor_codigo = "descriptor_codigo2";
    descriptor2.descriptor_valor = "descriptor_valor2";
    descriptores2.Add(descriptor2);
    item2.descriptores = descriptores2;

    //Añado los items
    items.Add(item1);
    items.Add(item2);
    detalle1.Items = items;
    detalles.Add(detalle1);


    docu.Detalle = detalles;
```

Bueno y ahora la parte importante, una vez que tienes tus datos introducidos en los objetos que hemos creado para poder obtener el fichero xml haríamos:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DocumentoXML));

    TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("./Documentos.xml");
    serializer.Serialize(writer, docu);
```

Y ya para rematar la faena voy a dejarte un ejemplo de como leer un fichero XML y convertirlo a un objeto de la clase que nos hemos creado `DocumentoXML` que no se si vas a utilizar pero por si a alguien le interesase.

```
    DocumentoXML docu = new DocumentoXML();
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DocumentoXML));

    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("./Documentos.xml"))
    {
        docu = (DocumentoXML) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
```

Bueno me ha quedado un poco largo pero espero que se entienda correctamente. Si te surge cualquier duda comenta y vamos viéndolas.

Comment: hola, probé tu código y anda bien, tengo un único detalle que espero me puedas aclarar, hice un ejemplo de item con la misma estructura que tienes tu, en tu xml y código, pero en mi caso, lo que es el **autorizaciones_organismos_externos**, me lo tira al inicio del ítem, a qué se puede deber eso? Gracias

Comment: El error te da al introducir los datos? Sería interesante ver el código sobre el q te da el error y la excepcion en sí.

Comment: lo voy a publicar como pregunta. Igual me costó un poco entender como se serializa peo creo que voy bien.