# Ordenar serialización en C# para Generar un archivo XML

Tags: c#, xml, serializacion

esta pregunta va en relación a una anterior que tenía, este es el [LINK](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/253459/problema-de-programacion-u-logica-para-limpiar-una-lista-en-c/255011?noredirect=1#comment474268_255011).

Bueno, estoy serializando un XML, esto gracias al @ElGerar que se dió el tiempo de explicarlo con una respuesta. Me costó un poco entenderlo peo creo que voy bien.

Mi duda es si la estructura junto con el código que tengo está bien ya que el resultado lo obtengo en otro orden, me explico

Este es el código de la parte general:

```
[XmlRoot("documento", Namespace = "")]
    public class DocumentoXML
    {
        [XmlElement("cabecera")]
        public List<CabeceraXML> Cabecera { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("documentosadjuntos")]
        public List<DocumentosAdjuntosXML> Documentos_Adjuntos { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("bultos")]
        public List<BultosXML> Bultos { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("contenedores")]
        public List<ContenedoresXML> Contenedores { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("detalle")]
        public List<DetalleXML> Detalle { get; set; }
    }
```

Mi duda está enfocada en el elemento **Detalle**, los otros ya los tengo cubiertos y andan bien, entonces, para el Detalle tengo lo siguiente:

```
public class DetalleXML
    {
        [XmlElement("item")]
        public List<ItemXML> Items { get; set; }
    }
```

Tengo que detalle contiene un item y este a su vez contiene otros elementos y dentro de ellos tengo dos **que están al final** que también contienen otros, las *autorizaciones* y los *descriptores*

```
public class ItemXML
    {
        [XmlElement("nro_item")]
        public string nro_item { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("codigo_arancelario")]
        public string codigo_arancelario { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("total_valor_ingreso")]
        public decimal total_valor_ingreso { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("autorizaciones_organismos_externos")]
        public List<AutorizacionesOrganismosExternosXML> AutorizacionesOrganismosExternos ;

        //[XmlElement("pdm_codigo")]
        //public string pdm_codigo { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("descriptores")]
        public List<DescriptoresXML> Descriptores;

    }
```

Y el código para las autorizaciones y los descriptores es el siguiente:

```
public class AutorizacionesOrganismosExternosXML
    {
        [XmlElement("autorizacion_organismos_externos")]
        public List<AutorizacionOrganismoExternoXML> autorizacion_organismos_externos{get;set;}
    }

    public class AutorizacionOrganismoExternoXML
    {
        [XmlElement("declara_certificado")]
        public string declara_certificado { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("organismo_externo_codigo")]
        public string organismo_externo_codigo { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("tipo")]
        public string tipo { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("numero")]
        public string numero { get; set; }



    }

    public class DescriptoresXML
    {
        [XmlElement("descriptor")]
        public List<DescriptorXML> descriptor { get; set; }
    }

    public class DescriptorXML
    {
        [XmlElement("descriptor_codigo")]
        public string descriptor_codigo { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("descriptor_valor")]
        public string descriptor_valor { get; set; }
    }
```

Ahora, el código que tengo para serializar el item con sus campos es el siguiente:

```
var detalles = new List<DetalleXML>();
var detalle1 = new DetalleXML();
var items = new List<ItemXML>();


var item1 = new ItemXML();
item1.nro_item = "01";
item1.codigo_arancelario = "AD001";
item1.total_valor_ingreso = 80.80m;

var autorizaciones = new List<AutorizacionesOrganismosExternosXML>();
var autorizacion = new AutorizacionesOrganismosExternosXML();
var au = new List<AutorizacionOrganismoExternoXML>();

var a = new AutorizacionOrganismoExternoXML();
a.declara_certificado = "S";
a.organismo_externo_codigo = "Capital";
a.tipo = "EL";
a.numero = "1202";


au.Add(a);
autorizacion.autorizacion_organismos_externos = au;
autorizaciones.Add(autorizacion);

item1.AutorizacionesOrganismosExternos = autorizaciones;

var Descriptores = new List<DescriptoresXML>();
var Descriptor = new DescriptoresXML();
var de = new List<DescriptorXML>();

var d = new DescriptorXML();
d.descriptor_codigo = "lalal";
d.descriptor_valor = "2012";

de.Add(d);
Descriptor.descriptor = de;
Descriptores.Add(Descriptor);
item1.Descriptores = Descriptores;


items.Add(item1);
detalle1.Items = items;

detalles.Add(detalle1);

var serial = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DocumentoXML));
TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("./Doc_prueba.xml");
serial.Serialize(writer, documento );
```

Si genero el XML me muestra de la siguiente forma el elemento del detalle:

```
<detalle>
    <item>
      <autorizaciones_organismos_externos>
        <autorizacion_organismos_externos>
          <declara_certificado>S</declara_certificado>
          <organismo_externo_codigo>Capital</organismo_externo_codigo>
          <tipo>EL</tipo>
          <numero>1202</numero>
        </autorizacion_organismos_externos>
      </autorizaciones_organismos_externos>
      <descriptores>
        <descriptor>
          <descriptor_codigo>lalal</descriptor_codigo>
          <descriptor_valor>2012</descriptor_valor>
        </descriptor>
      </descriptores>
      <nro_item>01</nro_item>
      <codigo_arancelario>AD001</codigo_arancelario>
      <cantidad_unidad_medida_arancelaria>45.34</cantidad_unidad_medida_arancelaria>
      <total_valor_ingreso>80.80</total_valor_ingreso>
    </item>
  </detalle>
```

Me está dejando las autorizaciones y los descriptores arriba, cuando en la estructura tengo que van los otros elementos primero, entonces no sé si el problema está en mi código o se debe a otra cosa.

Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declara un orden a cada elemenento en tu documento:

```
   [XmlElement("nro_item", Order=1)]
public string nro_item { get; set; }

[XmlElement("codigo_arancelario", Order=2)]
public string codigo_arancelario { get; set; }
```

Y asi con los demas elementos.

Comment: Buena, esto podría aplicarlo a todo el documento?

Comment: A todos los elementos xml declarados en tu documento, asi como el orden en los hijos.