# agregar XmlAttribute a documento XML usando Serializacion en c#

Tags: c#, xml, serialización

Muy Buenas, hace un tiempo me ayudaron a poder generar mi archivo xml usando serializacion, esto [ACÁ](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/253459/problema-de-programacion-u-logica-para-limpiar-una-lista-en-c)

El documento lo tengo generado y anda super bien, pero he estado buscando en google y no logro encontrar ejemplo de como agregar un atributo xmlns por como estoy generando mi archivo.

La mayoría de los casos es usando los atributos de esta forma:

```
XElement root = new XElement(ns+ “numbers”,
    from i in Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
    select new XElement(“number”,
        new XAttribute(“value”, i),
        new XAttribute(“square”, i*i)));
```

La forma de mi documento es la siguiente:

```
 public class sveXML
    {
        [XmlElement("documento", Order = 1)]
        public List<DocumentoXML> Documento_XML { get; set; }
    }

    public class DocumentoXML
    {
        [XmlAttribute("ID")]
        public string Value { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("xmlns")]
        public string Xmlns { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("cabecera", Order = 1)]
        public List<CabeceraXML> Cabecera { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("documentosadjuntos", Order = 2)]
        public List<DocumentosAdjuntosXML> Documentos_Adjuntos { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("bultos", Order = 3)]
        public List<BultosXML> Bultos { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("contenedores", Order = 4)]
        public List<ContenedoresXMLR> Contenedores { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("detalle", Order = 5)]
        public List<DetalleXML> Detalle { get; set; }
    }
```

Tengo dos atributos, el ID no tengo problema para llenarlo, pero a pesar de que le pongo un valor a **xmlns** no lo toma, pongo el código que tengo para esta parte del código:

```
   var documento = new List<DocumentoXML>();
   var doc = new DocumentoXML();

   doc.Value = "Documento101";
   doc.Xmlns = "Hola Mundo";
```

Estoy revisando estos dos links: [link1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlns?view=netframework-4.8) y [link2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializernamespaces?view=netframework-4.8) pero no estoy muy seguro de si tienen que ver con mi caso.

Muchas Gracias.

pd: Si se necesita que ponga más partes del código lo hago.

Comment: ¿Tienes que cambiar el valor cada vez? Normalmente el "namespace" de un elemento es fijo y parte del nombre del elemento, por eso se suele definirlo directamente con `[XmlElement(Namespace="http://example.com")]` en la declaración por el adjetivo `XmlElement`.

Comment: no, es un valor fijo, pero con lo que me dijiste funcionó y además que los estaba agregando en la clase equivocada. gracias!